# Adding SSL Certificate to Keystore

Tags: android

Can someone please guide me on how to add Certificate to Keystore(Android Mobile)...A sample code will be helpfull..

Comment: the certificate is a a.crt certificate.

Answer (score 6, accepted):

The keystore format you need is in the BouncyCastle jar, which you need to download. Then you create the keystore. Finally, you will need to extend the HTTPClient.

There's a simple example on how to that in [here](http://blog.antoine.li/index.php/2010/10/android-trusting-ssl-certificates/).

Comment: Upvote for pointing to a great resource, but you should probably copy the gist of the matter here, in case the link ever goes down

Comment: @Erez A. Korn: The link to the resource is no longer available.